# Create custom lockscreen for Android 2.3 and above

Tags: android

I want to create lockscreen app for Android 2.3 and above.

I already created lockscreen, but when you click on a home button on Android 5.x you can exit from a lockscreen, or when you click on an ad, or when you pull menu down and click on some option.

I would like that you can't exit lockscreen unless you type corrent passcode.

I saw one app in Google Play that does what I need. It's called [Lock screen password](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.green.banana.app.lockscreenpassword). Basically, lockscreen in this app is above everything. You can pull menu down and click on some option, but that option will open behind lockscreen. Same thing is with ad, if you click on an ad, it will open behind lockscreen. If you click on a home button, it will exit from everything behind lockscreen, but lockscreen will stay. The only way to exit is to type corrent passcode.

How they did it?

Comment: Check the accepted answer in the link below, it has further links to some github projects that might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding this to your manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

"android.intent.category.HOME" indicates that "this is the home activity, that is the first activity that is displayed when the device boots".

"android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" indicates that this activity "should be displayed in the top-level launcher".

You will also probably want to read about the KeyguardManager class though it seems like it's not vital to implement a lock screen.